# Copy JSON files from a private repository to the current one

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I've set up a YML file for a GitHub action to get some files from a private repo I have. The action seems to work without throwing any error (even the file names are showing up in the log) but the folder and the files are not showing up in the destination repository.

Can someone shed some light on what am I doing wrong?

This is my YML so far:

```
name: copy JSONs

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  copy_files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Copy files from private repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        repository: paramm/cron-jobs
        token: ghp_BLABLABALBALBALBABLABLA
        path: private-repo-files
    - name: Create directory for copied files
      run: |
        mkdir copied-files
        mv private-repo-files/*.json copied-files/
    - name: Add and commit copied files
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
        git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
        git add copied-files
        git commit -m "Add copied files from private repo"
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also `push` the updates at the end of the workflow?

Comment: yeah, I forgot that

Answer (score 0):

last line was missing:

```
git push origin main
```